# Difficultites installing akka (scala & ubuntu)

Tags: scala, ubuntu, akka

I'm trying to get akka (scala) on my ubuntu machine. Sorry to bother, but i'm encountering some difficulties...
I followed the install tutorial here : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html ; but cannot find the /bin directory needed here for the sbt install : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html. I have no idea where to put the .jar file, nor what to do then with the script.

Noob spotted.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I nearly succeeded, but an error still stops me while running the script:
5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved
[info] Set current project to bin (in build file:/export/home/babar/bin/)
I have no idea what to input here. Tje more i try the more i get "Not a valid command"...
What does it await?

Answer (score 3):

Akka is just a library. You don't "install" it. Instead simply use [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) or Maven or Gradle to include it as a dependency for your Scala/Java project. Refer to SBT docs on how to get started with this.

Comment: That is what i am trying to do with sbt, but cannot find the directory ~/bin, i have no /bin here. I am ignorant on what to do... should i create it ? I don't think it is normal not to have any so i suspect i have to execute some special tasks to proceed.  As pushy suggested, is the typesafe activator the reminding way? I tried to create a /bin with /sbt then copying the .jar and run the script written as mentioned, but the jarfile appears corrupted...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to start playing around with Akka and Scala is to download the [Typesafe Activator](http://typesafe.com/activator). You just need to unzip the downloaded file and start activator with `./activator ui`.

The Activator contains a lot of templates, including a Hello Akka template that is a nice way to get to know Akka and play around with it.

Note that you will need to have a JDK installed first. OpenJDK can be installed using apt-get under ubuntu, or you go to the java homepage and download an installer for the Oracle JDK there.

Answer (score 0):

if you followed sbt tutorial "~/bin" means "bin" subdirectory of your home directory. if you take a look at your .profile, you will see that by default ubuntu adds this subdirectory to your path if it exists. 
so,

1) create bin subdirectory in your $HOME
 2) copy appropriate jar(s) $HOME/bin 
 3) create script file make executable as instructed by tutorials 
 4) type source ~/.profile or start another terminal
 5) run sbt(preferebly in a directory that you plan to use for scala
    projects)